# What is macaroni cooked in milk called?

Tags: pasta, milk, language

Is there a name for the partial dish where you simmer macaroni in milk for 30-60 minutes? It's called [stuvade makaroner](https://www.arla.se/recept/stuvade-makaroner/) in Swedish:

[image: stuvade makaroner]

Comment: The linked recipe says 3-5 minutes, not 30-60 minutes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any food simmered in milk is referred to as *creamed* e.g. creamed corn. So I guess this would be creamed macaroni.

Comment: Careful here, as this might depend on the country you are located in. "Creamed macaroni" is a dessert in the UK.

Answer (score 5):

The linked recipe (while I don't read Swedish, Google helps) is for what in the UK we'd call *macaroni cheese* ("macaroni and cheese" to Americans).  It doesn't actually cook the macaroni in the milk, but in water: Translated excerpt:

> Cook macaroni according to the instructions on the package.

> Pour off the water in a colander and pour the macaroni back into the saucepan.

(then add the sauce and cheese)

Comment: Oh, well spotted. Definitely sounds like macaroni cheese!

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we have a dessert called "creamed macaroni". It usually comes in cans. I've never heard of anybody actually making it from scratch. It's basically macaroni in a creamy sweet sauce. There must be a recipe somewhere. I don't know if the pasta is actually cooked in milk or water though.

And yes it is as horrible as it sounds IMHO. I tried it once, that was enough. Although somebody must buy it, otherwise it wouldn't exist.

Comment: It's basically rice pudding made with pasta instead of rice.  Like rice pudding it can be plain and just sweet or made more interesting.  Recipes overlap with "macaroni pudding" to the extent that they're probably synonyms.

Comment: @ChrisH - yes, but yuk. Each to their own I suppose!

Comment: I've had it once, and it was OK, but I wouldn't fancy it tinned even though I occasionally eat tinned rice pudding, normally when camping or similarly in need of something hot and energy-giving with limited time or facilities. Tinned macaroni cheese has its place too - in emergency supplies IME.

Comment: @ChrisH To help put the emergency into perspective?